# Find the most similar line in a file

Tags: python, difflib

The program's intent is to gather a list of all programs on the computer and find the correct path based on user input. So if the input is `Audition` the program will return
`C:\Adobe\Audition CC 2014\Audition CC 2014.exe`.

I need it to search a txt file for a line that is most similar to whatever the user inputs. My code is as follows:

```python
import os
import subprocess
import getpass
import sys
import difflib
from difflib import SequenceMatcher as SM



user = getpass.getuser()

print(os.getcwd())
exeFile = (os.getcwd() + "/paths/programpaths.txt")


def get_filepaths(directory):

    file_paths = []  # List which will store all of the full filepaths.
    exes = open(os.getcwd() + "/paths/programpaths.txt", "w+")
    # Walk the tree.
    for root, directories, files in os.walk(directory):
        for filename in files:
            # Join the two strings in order to form the full filepath.
            filepath = os.path.join(root, filename)
            file_paths.append(filepath)  # Add it to the list.
            if filepath.endswith('exe') and "ninstall" not in filepath and "$RECYCLE.BIN" not in filepath:
                files = filepath.encode('cp850', errors='replace').decode('cp850')
                #print(files + "\n")
                exes.write(files + "\n")
    return file_paths  # Self-explanatory. 



if not os.path.exists(exeFile):
    print("List compilation should only happen once")
    print()
    print("Compiling list of installed programs")
    print("This may take a while")
    exes = open(os.getcwd() + "/paths/programpaths.txt", "a+")
    full_file_pathsx64 = get_filepaths('C:\Program Files')
    full_file_pathsx86 = get_filepaths('C:\Program Files (x86)')
    full_file_pathsgames = get_filepaths('G:\\')

# Run the above function and store its results in a variable.   
print("List compilation should only happen once")
print()



print("Done!")
pinput = input()



for line in open(exeFile):
    prog = line.split("\\")[-1]
    sim = difflib.get_close_matches(pinput, [prog], 1)
    print(sim)
```

However, this prints a blank bracket "[]" for every line in the file and does not just give me the one I need.

I know this is because I told it to do this for every line, but I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: would you mind to post code of function difflib.get_close_matches?

Comment: @galaxyan it's in the stdlib... and documented... the OP doesn't need to post that

Comment: `prog` is a string but should be a sequence of possibilites. So it’s interpreted as a list of characters instead.

Comment: @poke: good point. It doesn't sound like the problem he's asking about, but he must need to fix that too… I don't know if he meant ``(pinput, [prog], 1)` or `[:-1]` instead of `[-1]` or something on the previous line≥

Comment: @abarnert A better solution would maybe be `get_close_matches(pinput, file.splitlines(), 1)`

Comment: @poke I tried your suggestion and get the same result: A loooot of empty brackets. I just want it to print the closest line.

Comment: You should post some information about what your file looks like. All we can do right now is guess.

Comment: @poke: I'm pretty sure he'd at least want something like `[line.split("\\")[-1] for line in file]`, not `file.splitlines()`. But also, it sounds like he wants to check one match per line, not N matches spread over the whole file? Although I'm not nearly as sure about that part…

Answer (score 3):

The `get_close_matches(…, 1)` call is going to return either an empty list, or a list of exactly one match.

What you want to do, in English, is:

- If it's got an element, print it.
- Otherwise, don't do anything.

Translate that directly to python:

```
if sim:
    print(sim[0])
```

(You can write `else: pass` for "otherwise, don't do anything", or you can just not write anything.)

---

That solves the "don't print `[]` for every line, just print the matches".

But that raises another problem: You don't actually get any matches.

As poke explained in a comment, the second argument to `get_close_matches` is a list of possibilities to check against, but the value you're passing, `prog`, is a single string.

If it's not clear why it's a single string, look at this line:

```
prog = line.split("\\")[-1]
```

You `split` the string into a list of smaller strings, then you take just the last one with `[-1]`.

If you're curious why you don't get an error: a string is itself a sequence of strings, one for each character. So, if `prog` is `"abcde"`, then you're asking it to treat `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` as 5 separate possibilities, which is a perfectly reasonable thing to do, it just isn't likely to ever match anything.

---

I *think* what you want here may be just passing a list of this one possibility:

```
sim = difflib.get_close_matches(pinput, [prog], 1)
```

---

Or, alternatively, instead of searching for each possibility one at a time, you could build up a big list of all the possibilities, then search for them all at once:

```
progs = []
for line in open(exefile):
    progs.append(line.split("\\")[-1])
sim = difflib.get_close_matches(pinput, progs, 1)
```

But that only gets 1 match total, across the whole file, not 1 possible match per line. If you want *more* than 1 total, you can do that, but I'm not sure how well it works with a huge number. (You can always try it and see.)

---

Anyway, hopefully you understand what you actually want and don't have to guess. :)

Comment: This makes total sense, but I am very new to python so please bear with me. I put this in my code and it simply doesn't print anything. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @RyanAnderson: It looks like you have another problem, on top of this one—probably the one poke pointed out in a comment. I'll edit the answer to explain.

Comment: @RyanAnderson: Sorry it took so long; see the new edit.

Comment: @ap:  Not so concise anymore, unfortunately. :)

Comment: @abarnert Hey this sounds like exactly what I need and I really appreciate your help, but I still cannot seem to get past the bracket thing. To clarify, I _do_ want to get the closest match from the file. Just one match. I've updated my original post to hopefully help you guys help me. Thanks again!

Comment: @RyanAnderson: I already explained that in the first half of the answer: use `if sim: print(sim[0])` instead of just `print(sim)`. But in your updated code, you're still doing `print(sim)`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your full code you have posted now, this is my solution that probably solves your problem the best way:

```
with open(exeFile) as f:
    programs = { path.rsplit('\\', 1)[-1].rstrip()[:-4].lower(): path.strip() for path in f }

sim = difflib.get_close_matches(pinput.lower(), programs.keys(), 1)
if sim:
    print(programs[sim[0]])
```

The magic happens in the dictionary comprehension. For each `path` in the file, we generate the following name which serves as the key of the dictionary entry:

```
path.rsplit('\\', 1)[-1][:-4].lower()
```

So assuming a file path like `C:\Adobe\Audition CC 2014\Audition CC 2014.exe` it would first split *once from the right* by the slash and take the last element, so we would get `Audition CC 2014.exe`. Next, we strip off whitespace and then the `.exe` which we know is part of the file name based on how we generate the exefile. So we have `Audition CC 2014`. Next, we lower-case this so we have something that’s better comparable (because `difflib` is case-sensitive).

In the comparison, we then just get the close matches from the keys of the dictionary (which is just the lower-cased program name). We compare that against the lower-cased user input.

Once we got a result, we print the *path* that belongs to the matched key. This is the reason why we built a dictionary above; otherwise we would have to search the file again to find the full path.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much! However, it seems we have one last problem: Accuracy. For example, typing "Audition" returns "G:\Steam\SteamApps\common\Plants vs. Zombies\Plants vs. Zombies.exe" Thanks again for all your help

Comment: Yeah, the accuracy (or the lack of) comes from the difflib. You can try playing around with the `cutoff` parameter and see if it helps. Otherwise, you might want to look into different comparison strategies (e.g. using the levenshtein distance or some other kind of fuzzy matching)

Answer (score 0):

its always good to understand what you are actually trying to do

first define what you mean by "closest" (often times with strings this is known as hamming distance)

```
def hamming_distance(s1,s2):
    #first elimate non-letters
    s1 = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]","",s1)
    s2 = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]","",s2)
    #the distance is the sum of all instance with differing letters in this case
    return sum(a!=b for a,b in izip_longest(s1,s2))
```

then you simply need to iterate over the file and find the "closest match"

```
user_input = input("Enter String:")
print(min(open("file_of_strings.txt"),key=lambda x:hamming_distance(x,user_input)))
```

of coarse once you understand the magic you can probably get a marginal speedup using difflib

Answer (score 0):

If your `exefile` candidate list is small, then pre-load them into memory (in a list), then execute `difflib.get_close_matches`, eg:

```
import difflib

with open(exefile) as fin:
    progs = [line.rpartition('\\', line)[2] for line in fin]
    sim = difflib.get_close_matches(pinput, progs, 1)
```

On the overhand, if it's very large and you can't support the RAM, then use a heapq:

```
import difflib, heapq

with open(exefile) as fin:
    progs = (line.rpartition('\\'), line)[2] for line in fin)
    sim = heapq.nlargest(1, progs, key=lambda L: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, pinput, L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the document for get_close_matches(). It seems the second parameter should be list, so your code can be wrote as:

```
for line in open(exefile):
    prog = line.split("\\")[-1]
    prog = [item for item in prog.split(' ')]
    sim = difflib.get_close_matches(pinput, prog, 1)
    print(sim)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open(exefile) as f:
    possibilities = [line.split("\\")[-1].rstrip("\n") for line in f]
print(difflib.get_close_matches(pinput, possibilities, 1, 0)[0])
```

The key here is that get_close_matches doesn't have to return any matches at all. From the docs:

> get_close_matches(word, possibilities[, n][, cutoff])
>
> cutoff (default 0.6) is a float in the range [0, 1]. Possibilities that don’t score at least that similar to word are ignored.

So if you use `cutoff=0`, get_close_matches has to return something - the best match.